# How to fix "Could not find or load main class com.install4j.runtime.launcher.UnixLauncher" error when starting the nexus service

Tags: redhat, nexus, systemd, install4j, permission-denied

Operating system: Red Hat Entreprise Linux server release 7.7

nexus version: 3.18.1-01

When renewing the SSL certificate of Nexus on the server, I first replaced the old certificate under /opt/nexus/etc/ssl with the new one.
I put a new keystore with the new certificate and the same password as before with the same name in the same place and then ran `/opt/nexus/bin/nexus restart`.

Before the service was running and the URL was reachable, but since then I get the following error:

> Could not find or load main class
> com.install4j.runtime.launcher.UnixLauncher.

And the command `journalctl -u nexus` gives the following error:

> ```
>      Failed to start nexus service. 
>      Failed at step EXEC spawning /var/nexus/bin/nexus: Permission denied.
> ```

i tried a lot of things i found on the internet to fix this but unfortunately without success.

1. put the nexus user in the **nexus.rc** file

> run_as_user="nexus"

In the beginning it was like this:

> #run_as_user=""

That means, the nexus server is run with root and I tried to run it with the user nexus. Unfortunately this did not work.

I also tried the following:

2. changed the permission and owner for the "**/opt/nexus**" and "**/var/nexus**" folders (tested with *root* and *nexus* too).
3. moved the file **.install4j** to **/opt/nexus/**
4. at the end I wanted to test again with the old certificate and renamed the new one und the new key. I thought it was because of the new certificate.... But I still get the same error:

> Could not find or load main class
> com.install4j.runtime.launcher.UnixLauncher

Something is wrong since I stopped and restarted the nexus service but i don't know what exactly.

Can you help me please? I would be very grateful.

Answer (score 0):

Check the ownership of the PID file:

https://help.sonatype.com/display/NXRM3/Run+as+a+Service#RunasaService-PIDFile

Comment: Thank you @rseddon for your answer! 
I tried it but unfortunately the same error is still present.